# I need to delete resource group and after some time restore. Best way to do that?

Tags: azure

I need to delete the resource group with all its content and after some time restore that resource group with all its content as it was before deletion. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Look into [tag:azure-cli] on how to automate the desired steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this will be by using Terraform or ARM template deployments. To optimize and save costs, this is usually used in non-prod environments where you will delete all the resources after business hours and schedule it to deploy again next morning.

The Export Template option under the Automation subsection allows you to get the template of the resource group. However, it is not complete and will not work correctly if you redeploy. But this is the right way of doing it.

Comment: This document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/quickstart-create-templates-use-the-portal#export-a-custom-template says that "Export template" under "Automation" generates ARM template. You have mentioned ARM template works well but also mentioning that "Export template" under "Automation" does not works well. Could you clarify this more? Thank you.

Comment: When you write "it is not complete and will not work correctly if you redeploy" are you refering to the limitations that described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/export-template-portal#limitations   ?

Comment: What I meant is the configurations within the resources. Suppose if there is a VM in the resource group and it is being deleted today and redeployed tomorrow using the template exported before deleting it, none of the configurations within the VM will be available. So this has to be carefully done for each type of resource by taking required backups. Hope I was able to answer to your expectations! @Alex

Comment: Thank you for clarifications. I understand the part about VMs (OS, programs,etc) or other services that may contain something that is not related to actual Azure configuration and that is why may I need separate backup of them (VM image, etc). But what about actual parts of the Azure and their configuration? Will all Azure configuration be copied completely? My workgroup consists of Vnet, VPN Gateway and Azure SQL managed instance. Am I understand correctly that in my case template should contain everything to recreate my workgroup from the template later? Thank you.